# Callback is not called after execution without any errors

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, mandrill

I am struggleing with the following code. The request is sent but no callback is called. I also get no error but emails are sent! Do you have any idea?

```
var userPointer = webhook.get("user");
userPointer.fetch().then(function(user){

    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({ 
        method: 'POST', 
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        }, 
        url: 'https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send-template.json', 
        body: {
            template_name: webhook.get("mandrillTemplateSlug"),
            template_content: null,
            key: user.get("apiKey"),
            message: {
                subject: webhook.get("subject"),
                from_email: "example@mail.com",
                from_name: "System",
                to: userData
            },
            async: false
         }
    },{
        success: function(httpResponse) {
            console.log(httpResponse);
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've separated the options object into two separate objects:

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    },
    url: 'https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send-template.json',
    body: {
        template_name: webhook.get("mandrillTemplateSlug"),
        template_content: null,
        key: user.get("apiKey"),
        message: {
            subject: webhook.get("subject"),
            from_email: "example@mail.com",
            from_name: "System",
            to: userData
        },
        async: false
    }
}, { // <=== Remove these, replace with just a comma
    success: function(httpResponse) {
        console.log(httpResponse);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

It should probably just be one, like this:

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    },
    url: 'https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send-template.json',
    body: {
        template_name: webhook.get("mandrillTemplateSlug"),
        template_content: null,
        key: user.get("apiKey"),
        message: {
            subject: webhook.get("subject"),
            from_email: "example@mail.com",
            from_name: "System",
            to: userData
        },
        async: false
    },
    success: function(httpResponse) {
        console.log(httpResponse);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```